# Optimization of nested for loops for using pandas function to speed up the process execution

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, recommendation-engine, execution-time

How can i optimize to speed the process execution.
We have 15000 students and 850 bench
We need to  recommend for each student with 850 bench
Presently it takes 8 days to execute for 15000 students to recommend each student 850 bench

##### DATA DESCRIPTION

- student_correlation_dataframe shape is (15000*15000)
- student_bench_data shape is 15000 rows and 18 features which as categorical values as well
- student_bench_data_dataframe is the function where it produces dataframe with shape of 15000*18
- student_correlation_pivot_dataframe is the function which produces dataframe with correlation matrix

```
    results = []
    for student_id in tqdm(unique_student_list):
        student_bench_data = student_bench_data_dataframe # 
        student_correlation_dataframe = student_correlation_pivot_dataframe

        similar_bench_corr = student_correlation_dataframe.loc[student_id].sort_values(ascending=False)

        bench_by_similar_student = pd.DataFrame()

        for i in range(len(similar_bench_corr)):
            if similar_bench_corr.index[i] != student_id:
                student_top_booking_bench = student_bench_data[
                    student_bench_data["studentid"] == similar_bench_corr.index[i]
                ]
                student_top_booking_bench = student_top_booking_bench[
                    [
                        "bench_id",
                        "Frequency",
                        "bench_name",
                        "bench_type",
                        "country",
                        "city",
                        "site",
                        "floor",
                        "building",
                    ]
                ].reset_index(drop=True)
                student_top_booking_bench["Freq_Corr"] = (
                    student_top_booking_bench["Frequency"] * similar_bench_corr.iloc[i]
                )
                bench_by_similar_student = pd.concat([student_top_booking_bench, bench_by_similar_student])

        # Sort the dataframe on Qty_CORR
        # Aggregate the Qty Correlation by Product

        bench_by_similar_student = bench_by_similar_student.groupby(
            ["bench_id", "bench_name", "bench_type", "country", "city", "site", "floor", "building"]
        ).agg({"Freq_Corr": "sum"})
        bench_by_similar_student.reset_index(inplace=True)

        # ignore the bench already booked by the input student
        # merge bench_by_similar_student and students booked benchs and
        #  drop the rows with No of Bookings being Not Null

        input_student_top_booked_bench = student_bench_data[student_bench_data["studentid"] == student_id]
        df_merge = pd.merge(
            bench_by_similar_student,
            input_student_top_booked_bench[["bench_id", "No_of_Bookings"]],
            how="left",
            on="bench_id",
        )

        bench_recommend_to_students = df_merge[df_merge["No_of_Bookings"].isnull()]

        # sort the dataframe on the Qty_Corr

        bench_recommend_to_students = bench_recommend_to_students.sort_values("Freq_Corr", ascending=False)[
            [
                "bench_id",
                "bench_name",
                "bench_type",
                "country",
                "city",
                "site",
                "floor",
                "building",
                "Freq_Corr",
            ]
        ].reset_index(drop=True)

        bench_recommend_to_students["studentid"] = student_id

        results.append(bench_recommend_to_students)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should **never do a `df = pd.concat([df, ...])`** in a loop. This create a `n` growing dataframe resulting in a *quadratic time*. Use a list to append your dataframe blocks and **`pd.join`** at the end instead. This is certainly the most critical point slowing down your code.

Moreover, doing `student_bench_data["studentid"] == similar_bench_corr.index[i]` is not a good idea either since it iterate over all the `student_bench_data` dataframe row so to find the one matching with `similar_bench_corr.index[i]`. This is not efficient. You can perform a **`groupby` to find the all the groups**. In fact, you can do this **only once in the beginning**: you can compute all the groups and put them in a dictionary so to finally fetch the dictionary in the innermost loop. You could even filter the 9 columns during this pre-computation.

These two modification should drastically improve the execution time. I expect it to run in minutes instead of several days.